# How do you import part of the standard library in Coq?

Tags: coq, beginner

How do you import part of the standard library in Coq?

- How do you import `Nat` specifically?
- Why is reporting `Nat` *not* required to use `+`?

I did the warmup exercise of proving commutativity of addition in Coq, as described [here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/8). I have a verbose solution in Appendix A of this question.

I added a slightly modified version of `Lemma comm_plus` in Nick Dattani's answer to the buffer.

This isn't the entire proof. `coqtop` (via Proof-General) refuses to advance past `Nat.add_0_r`.

```
Theorem comm_plus_truenat: forall a b, a + b = b + a.
Proof.
  intros. induction a.
  - simpl.
    symmetry.
    apply Nat.add_0_r.
Qed
```

Attempting to run this incomplete proof produces the error `Error: The reference Nat.add_0_r was not found in the current environment.`.

This makes sense, I haven't imported the `Nat` library.

However, adding `Require Nat.`, adding `Import Nat.`, and adding both all produce the same error message.

How does one import `Nat` (or another part of the standard library)?
I'm also curious why the *theorem* which uses `+`, wasn't rejected.

---

#### Appendix A:

verbose, extremely naive proof of commutativity of natural number addition in Coq.

---

````
Inductive nat : Set :=
| O : nat
| S : nat -> nat .

Fixpoint plus (a b : nat) {struct a} : nat :=
  match a with
  | O => b
  | S a'' => S (plus a'' b)
  end.

Theorem comm_plus: forall (a b : nat), plus a b = plus b a.
Proof.
  induction a.
  intros.
  simpl.
  unfold plus.
  induction b.
  tauto.
  simpl.
  simpl in IHb.
  f_equal.
  tauto.
  intros.
  simpl.
  rewrite IHa.
  induction b.
  simpl.
  tauto.
  simpl.
  f_equal.
  tauto.
Qed.
```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended import to get the many lemmas associated with `nat` is [`Require Import Arith`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/coq-library.html#peanos-arithmetic-nat). This includes `PeanoNat`.

Similarly, for `N` import `NArith` and for `Z` import `ZArith`.

Answer (score 3):

In order for `Nat.add_0_r` to be in scope, one must add `Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.`.

The documentation for this library [is here](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.html).

Here is the explanation of what the `Nat` module is, which is inside this library is and what signatures it implements.

```
Module Nat
 <: NAxiomsSig
 <: UsualDecidableTypeFull
 <: OrderedTypeFull
 <: TotalOrder.
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `Require Import Arith.` as suggested by Li-yao. To add to this answer, the reason why `+` is in scope when you start using Coq without importing anything is because Coq's library has a "prelude" which imports a few basic notions that are really useful to have everywhere. This includes not only operators such as `+` (notation for `Nat.add` BTW), but also the definition of natural numbers and even of `=` (none of this is a primitive notion in Coq's language). In fact, even the implication arrow (`->`) is a notation that is defined in Coq's prelude.

You can run Coq without the prelude, and some (like the [HoTT library](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT)) actually rely on this. To do this, you can pass the `-noinit` option to `coqtop` or `coqide`. If you use this option, then your initial statement won't work anymore, and even the code from your appendix won't (because you rely on things like `->` and `=`... and tactics, which are also not loaded by default with this option).