# Defining Lists and Prove Associativity of Append

Tags: usage, beginner, inductive-type, induction, rosetta-stone

When I saw [this question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/3/whats-the-hello-world-for-proof-assistants) asking what is the "*Hello, World!*" for proof assistants I immediately thought of that exercise. Not a long time after [this answer](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/42/105) by Couchy was proposed.

Therefore, I am asking this question: How do I canonically define lists, append and prove its associativity in your favourite theorem prover?

---

<sub>Of course, you are encouraged to provide additional theorems which you think highlights an interesting feature/quirk of that particular theorem prover!</sub>

Comment: I think this is not a good question, but it does bring up something important: we need a **proof assistants Rosetta stone**.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I agree about the latter, but that would make an even worse question. You may edit the question to open it up some more, but my fear is that it'll quickly gets subjective.

Comment: I added a [tag:rosetta-stone] tag for now and proposed some usage guidance. Maybe we can treat it as a specific type of question for now, similar to the `code-review` tag (that appears to have fallen into disuse?).

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I believe that there was a decision to change `code-review` to `proof-review`, which is more in line with what people would actually be asking.

Comment: If we do allow questions like this, I would be inclined to make them community wiki.  I'm not sure we should have them at all, though.

Comment: I made a [meta question](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/should-we-allow-rosetta-stone-style-questions) for this issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because StackExchange sites are not the right format for such information. Note I do not say questions. See Meta question with my answer. In short consider GitHub pages or similar.

Comment: @Wno-all: I was not suggesting that the Rosetta stone would be part of this site. It just needs to exist, like the [Effects Rosetta Stone](https://github.com/effect-handlers/effects-rosetta-stone).

Comment: @AndrejBauer Would [this](https://github.com/hwayne/lets-prove-leftpad) (pointed to by Clément) qualify as a Rosetta stone?

Comment: @Zimmi48 yes and no. I believe he had [this](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) in mind, so something that covers more problems than just left padding.

Comment: @Wno-all: I kind of hate the phrase "provably correct" because it is misused 90% of the time, but it's a start. It would be more useful to have many different (and relevant) examples done in various proof assitants. The Effects Rosetta Stone figured out some thing, for instance, the example must have an informal description which is translated to a proof assistant in whatever way is idomatic (as opposed to forcing a single style on everyone).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little list module written in Adga. To do this we are going to need `cong` -rule, and it resides in PropositionalEquality -module.

```
module lists where
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
```

Agda uses GADT-like syntax for its inductive types.

```
data List (a : Set) : Set where
  nil : List a
  cons : a → List a → List a
```

Here's the append, implemented by matching on the first argument. I defined it for an infix symbol to make it bit more convenient to describe associativity of append.

```
_++_ : {a : Set} → List a → List a → List a
_++_ nil ys = ys
_++_ (cons x xs) ys = cons x (xs ++ ys)
```

And here's the associativity property for append.

```
appendAssociative : {a : Set} → (xs ys zs : List a)
                  → (xs ++ ys) ++ zs ≡ xs ++ (ys ++ zs)
appendAssociative nil ys zs = refl
appendAssociative (cons x xs) ys zs = cong (cons x) (appendAssociative xs ys zs)
```

Comment: Using the `rewrite` construct you can avoid importing the standard library just for one little `cong`.

Comment: If you get into the habit of using `rewrite` a lot (and `with` too), you're setting yourself up for a lot of pain in the future. They both work, but don't scale all that well, at least in my experience.

Comment: The standard library is also being used for `_≡_`. If you didn't import that, you'd have to define your own and bind it to the relevant builtin in order to use `rewrite`. You could alternatively avoid the builtin pragma by manually desugaring the `rewrite` to a `with`.

Comment: @mudri `_≡_` is builtin. If you look at stdlib closely, you will see that it merely re-exports `Agda.Builtin.Equality`. PS. if you don't include the `@` sign I won't be notified.