Using Coq after installation
I have installed Coq from my package manager on ubuntu.  How can I run some basic theorem that I can easily understand its proof with Coq.

Please do not pose questions everywhere, you can add some follow-up questions in your previous thread.

It's unclear if you're asking 1) how to install an IDE for Coq, https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/43/proof-assistants-for-beginners-a-comparison/580#580 or 2) an example program to test your installation https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/8/75

I installed Coq but do not know how to run simple examples.  What do I have to do exactly ?

@Djoser "Running a Coq program" is essentially type-checking the program you have written. In most cases one uses COQC, the official compiler for Coq, to compile Coq programs. You can read the introductory chapters in the book Software Foundations for more information. CoqIDE, VSCoq, etc. can check your program on the fly with some shortcuts.

And, for an even gentler introduction, Software Foundations in Coq
by M.R. Clarkson - YouTube

You need an IDE to use Coq, since it should be used in an interactive manner.
Popular options are:

CoqIDE
Visual Studio Code with VSCoq extension
Emacs with Proof General (optionally with CompanyCoq)

Once you do so, you can step through a proof. For example, you can copy the following script into your IDE
Goal 2 + 2 = 4.
Proof.
  trivial.
Qed.

and 'step through' the proof.
Another option is to use JSCoq on your browser.

I would like to use Emacs for this.
